# running vlm file with python-vlc

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc

i need to run a vlm file with two streaming source. My file works correctly with vlc.exe and follow command `vlc.exe" --vlm-conf "%cd%\mosaic_vlc3.vlm"`
i can run a simple streaming source with python-vlc with follow commands
  `media = vlc.Media("http://xx.xx.xx.xx/video2.mjpg")`
  `media_player.set_media(media)`
  `media_player.play()`

but i'm no luck with .vlm file.
How can i do?

thanks